# C# WPF application is using too much memory while GC.GetTotalMemory() is low

Tags: c#, wpf, memory-leaks

I wrote little WPF application with 2 threads - main thread is GUI thread and another thread is worker.
App has one WPF form with some controls. There is a button, allowing to select directory.
After selecting directory, application scans for .jpg files in that directory and checks if their thumbnails are in hashtable. if they are, it does nothing. else it's adding their full filenames to queue for worker. 
Worker is taking filenames from this queue, loading JPEG images (using WPF's JpegBitmapDecoder and BitmapFrame), making thumbnails of them (using WPF's TransformedBitmap) and adding them to hashtable.
Everything works fine, except memory consumption by this application when making thumbnails for big images (like 5000x5000 pixels). I've added textboxes on my form to show memory consumption (GC.GetTotalMemory() and Process.GetCurrentProcess().PrivateMemorySize64) and was very surprised, cuz GC.GetTotalMemory() stays close to 1-2 Mbytes, while private memory size constantly grows, especially when loading new image (~ +100Mb per image).
Even after loading all images, making thumbnails of them and freeing original images, private memory size stays at ~700-800Mbytes. My VirtualBox is limited to 512Mb of physical memory and Windows in VirtualBox starts to swap alot to handle this huge memory consumption. I guess I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know how to investigate this problem, cuz according to GC, allocated memory size is very low.

Attaching code of thumbnail loader class:

```
class ThumbnailLoader
{
    Hashtable thumbnails;
    Queue<string> taskqueue;
    EventWaitHandle wh;
    Thread[] workers;
    bool stop;
    object locker;
    int width, height, processed, added;

    public ThumbnailLoader()
    {
        int workercount,i;
        wh = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        thumbnails = new Hashtable();
        taskqueue = new Queue<string>();
        stop = false;
        locker = new object();
        width = height = 64;
        processed = added = 0;
        workercount = Environment.ProcessorCount;
        workers=new Thread[workercount];
        for (i = 0; i < workercount; i++) {
            workers[i] = new Thread(Worker);
            workers[i].IsBackground = true;
            workers[i].Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            workers[i].Start();
        }
    }

    public void SetThumbnailSize(int twidth, int theight)
    {
        width = twidth;
        height = theight;
        if (thumbnails.Count!=0) AddTask("#resethash");
    }

    public void GetProgress(out int Added, out int Processed)
    {
        Added = added;
        Processed = processed;
    }

    private void AddTask(string filename)
    {
        lock(locker) {
            taskqueue.Enqueue(filename);
            wh.Set();
            added++;
        }
    }

    private string NextTask()
    {
        lock(locker) {
            if (taskqueue.Count == 0) return null;
            else {
                processed++;
                return taskqueue.Dequeue();
            }
        }
    }

    public static string FileNameToHash(string s)
    {
        return FormsAuthentication.HashPasswordForStoringInConfigFile(s, "MD5");
    }

    public bool GetThumbnail(string filename,out BitmapFrame thumbnail)
    {
        string hash;
        hash = FileNameToHash(filename);
        if (thumbnails.ContainsKey(hash)) {
            thumbnail=(BitmapFrame)thumbnails[hash];
            return true;
        }
        AddTask(filename);
        thumbnail = null;
        return false;
    }

    private BitmapFrame LoadThumbnail(string filename)
    {
        FileStream fs;
        JpegBitmapDecoder bd;
        BitmapFrame oldbf, bf;
        TransformedBitmap tb;
        double scale, dx, dy;
        fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);
        bd = new JpegBitmapDecoder(fs, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
        oldbf = bd.Frames[0];
        dx = (double)oldbf.Width / width;
        dy = (double)oldbf.Height / height;
        if (dx > dy) scale = 1 / dx;
        else scale = 1 / dy;
        tb = new TransformedBitmap(oldbf, new ScaleTransform(scale, scale));
        bf = BitmapFrame.Create(tb);
        fs.Close();
        oldbf = null;
        bd = null;
        GC.Collect();
        return bf;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        lock(locker) {
            stop = true;
        }
        AddTask(null);
        foreach (Thread worker in workers) {
            worker.Join();
        }
        wh.Close();
    }

    private void Worker()
    {
        string curtask,hash;
        while (!stop) {
            curtask = NextTask();
            if (curtask == null) wh.WaitOne();
            else {
                if (curtask == "#resethash") thumbnails.Clear();
                else {
                    hash = FileNameToHash(curtask);
                    try {
                        thumbnails[hash] = LoadThumbnail(curtask);
                    }
                    catch {
                        thumbnails[hash] = null;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like something going on with the Large Object Heap... Can you get performance counters on its size over time as you process images? The LOH doesn't collect the same way standard memory does, and (if I remember correctly) is much more susceptible to fragmentation...

Comment: This could well be a bug in WPF which has several known issues with unmanaged memory. I would recommend you to report this at Connect (http://connect.microsoft.com/). If the memory leak gets problematic for your application and you can't get a fix you could move the critical parts of your code to another process or AppDomain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem.
Just had to replace BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad with BitmapCacheOption.None :)

Comment: @Dmitry: You should mark the answer as the accepted answer.  If this was a "reply" to Nymaen's answer, you shoudl mark that answer as the accepted one (click the check), and include this as a Comment, not as a separate answer...

Comment: I couldn't reply to Nymaen's answer because I wrote this earlier than he wrote his answer.

Answer (score 10):

I suspect that `BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad` is adding the images to the Framework's memory footprint, but since you do not own the objects in the image cache, they do not appear in the results from `GC` method calls. Try using `BitmapCacheOption.None` instead and see if that solves your memory issues. Note: Doing this will have a drastic performance impact.

Answer (score 2):

I think it has to do with images - the underlying object of Image class is unmanaged, because of this memory consumed by them is not included in GC counters.

They also require extra care about how you dispose of them - managed memory consumption of them is very low so GC does not really pay attention, but the unamanged memory - you can see it.

The bottom line - it is not enough to let them go out of scope, you have to explicitly call dispose on them when you are done.

Comment: There is no Dispose() method in BitmapImage class.