# Why is memory for large images not registering in GetTotalMemory or CLRProfiler

Tags: c#, memory-management

My app displays a single high resolution image. When I display an image the task manager shows memory useage of 350Mb, but GetTotalMemory returns 2.5Mb, and CLRProfiler shows root memory useage of 2.0Mb

Why is loading a 24M pixel image into a BitmapImage object not registering in GetTotalMemory or CLRProfiler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2557278/c-sharp-wpf-application-is-using-too-much-memory-while-gc-gettotalmemory-is-lo

Comment: @dcastro It looks perfect, thanks, but has not changed my results

Comment: Form the suggested answer by @dcastro looks like the reason is that the memory is unmanaged, hence it will not show up in the `GetTotalMemory` call and the CLRProfiler.

Comment: @NedStoyanov Exactly. And `GC.GetTotalMemory` only accounts for managed memory. I should have linked to the [this specific answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2557351/857807) instead.

Comment: @dcastro That answer does seem to answer my case, though I'm confused as to why BitmapCacheOption.None worked for the poster of the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET Framework classes that manipulate images, like System.Drawing.Bitmap and System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource, are *wrapper classes*.  They don't actually do the heavy lifting involved with imaging, they pass the job on to previously existing imaging apis in Windows.  System.Drawing uses GDI+, a set of C functions that are pinvoked.  System.Windows uses WIC, the Windows Imaging Component, a COM api.

Naturally, these image apis don't know anything about the GC heap.  They were written in native C++ and use the memory management functions provided by the operating system.  Like VirtualAlloc(), HeapAlloc() and MapViewOfFile().

Accordingly, you cannot see the address space consumed by this native code with managed memory profilers or GC class methods.  Not something you'd ever want to try to find out either, there is a lot of this kind of pinvoke/COM interop buried in the .NET Framework.  A decent memory profiler (i.e. not CLRProfiler) can give you an idea how much of this unmanaged address space is used, it however won't break it down well like it can for managed code.  SysInternals' VMMap is a decent utility with the right price to get a look under the covers.